# Grouping lines with XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I'm writing an Excel file with Python and XlsxWriter in which I'd like to group elements in 2 levels. Several 'boards' contain elements grouped by 'list'. I'd like to group all elements of the same 'list' and all the elements of the 'board' together.

After many attempts I did not succeed in getting the following result:

[image: Excel example of expected result]

Can someone help me understand how the function below works:

```
worksheet.set_row(1, None, None, {'level': 1})
```

I've followed the [example](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_outline1.html#ex-outline1) given in the documentation but I don't know what level to set on each line to have 2 grouping levels working as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like the following which matches the first part of your screenshot.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('outline.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_row(1, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(2, None, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_row(3, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(4, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(5, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(6, None, None, {'level': 1})

worksheet.set_row(8, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(9, None, None, {'level': 1})

worksheet.set_row(12, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(13, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(14, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(15, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(16, None, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_row(17, None, None, {'level': 1})
worksheet.set_row(18, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(19, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(20, None, None, {'level': 2})
worksheet.set_row(21, None, None, {'level': 1})

workbook.close()
```

Output:

[image]

The trick is to fill in the level 1 rows where you need a contiguous grouping. Note that in the example there are values from row 1-6, 8-9 and 12-21 (zero indexed).

**Update**: Added row 12-23 grouping in response to the follow-on question below. Updated image as well.

Comment: Thanks this part works fine, but how do I treat the case of the line 18 ? If I leave it empty it split the 'board 4' in two.

Comment: We must know that setting twice the level doesn't work. We can't iterate a loop setting the level and adding an other level at the end of the loop on the last element.

Comment: @Eric - The row you're calling "line 18" (which is row 17 in XlsxWriter) should be level 1. Basically, the level indicates how many of the continuous vertical bars to draw on that row. Dots and "minus boxes" (or plus boxes) do not count toward the level.

Comment: @Eric I updated the sample code in relation to your question.